# Is $l^{\infty}$ subpace $s(\mathbb{F})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let be $s(\mathbb{F})$ a all sequence with term in $\mathbb{F}$ ($\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$). Denoted one element of $s(\mathbb{F})$, that $x=(x_j)$. Let be $$l^{\infty} = \{x\in s(\mathbb{F}); \sum_{j=0}^\infty |x_j|^\infty<\infty\}.$$

Show that $l^{\infty}$ is subpace of $s(\mathbb{F})$.

I got solved 1 and 3 conditions to $l^{\infty}$ be a subpace from $s(\mathbb{F})$. I want help with the proof of the condition 2 please.

**Conditions**

1. The zero vector, $0$, is in $W$.
2. If $u$ and $v$ are elements of $W$, then the sum $u + v$ is an element of $W$.
3. If $u$ is an element of $W$ and $c$ is a scalar from $K$, then the product $cu$ is an element of $W$.

Comment: What does $|x_j|^\infty$ mean?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{F}$? $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? Or something more sophisticated? And I reiterate Davide Giraudo's question: what is $|x_j|^\infty$?

Comment: yes $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. $|\cdot|$ is a module in complex case and absolute value function in real case.

Comment: $|x_j|^\infty$ mean absolute value of x elevate to infinite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the triangle inequality:
if $x,y\in\ell^\infty$, $||x_j+y_j||_\infty\leq ||x_j||_\infty+||y_j||_\infty$ for all $j$; then it should be straightforward to prove that the series $\sum_{j=1}^n||x_j+y_j||_\infty$ converges.

Comment: I need prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j+y_j|^\infty<\infty$, but $\sum_{j=1}^n||x_j+y_j||_\infty \neq \sum_{j=1}^n|x_j+y_j|^\infty$.

Comment: In this case, it is the same for module and/or absolute value. Both satisfy the triangle inequality. Just replace the "||" by "|" in my answer.

Comment: then By the the triangle inequality i will be able to say $|x_j+y_j|^\infty\leq |x_j|^\infty+|y_j|^\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Both absolute value and module satisfy $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$.

Comment: Ho I will be able to prove If $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ then  $|a+b|^\infty\leq |a|^\infty+|b|^\infty$?

Comment: You just said earlier that your $|.|^\infty$ _was_ either the module or the absolute value. In that case, you dont have to prove $|a+b|^\infty\leq |a|^\infty+|b|^\infty$: __it is known__.

Comment: is these expression in wikipedia?

Comment: Amongst other sources, yes. Have you looked by yourself?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties

(Keep in mind that Wikipedia is _not_ the ultimate reference.)

Comment: thank by your reply and time, sorry by my insistence. I cann't see where say $|a+b|^\infty\leq |a|^\infty+|b|^\infty$.

Comment: Because nobody uses this notation: you said earlier that this was a notation for either absolute value or module. The page I gave the url to says that both absolute value and module are subadditive (i.e, have the property discussed above).

Comment: $|x|^{\infty}$ mean absolute value of $x$ elevate to infinite. Not notation. Subadditive form url above is $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. :(

Comment: ?! I give up. Bringing a number "to the power infinite" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Why doesn't mean anything?.

Comment: What does it mean to you?
If $|x|<1$, $|x|^n$ goes to 0 when $n\to\infty$.
If $|x|=1$, it stays equal to 1.
Otherwise, it is not defined -- it goes to infinity. And I'm not even sure "limit when $n$ goes to infinity" is what you mean.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8606/discussion-between-juaninf-and-clement-c)